# BigQuery: Use the credentials from JSON not working for the terminal

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-authentication

I'm new with the google api, and I would appreciate your help for a problem that I'm facing:
When I try to use the credentials from a JSON file in the terminal it does not work, but when I try to use the same credentials for python it works, I'll share with you how I am using the credentials:

in python:

```
import os
from google.cloud import bigquery

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/Users/my_user/Desktop/works/credentials/service_account.json"

client = bigquery.Client('my_project')
job = client.get_job('job_id')

print(job.errors)
```

the previous code works,

in terminal:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/my_user/Desktop/works/credentials/service_account.json"

bq show -j job_id 

User does not have bigquery.jobs.get permission
for job my_project:US.job_id
```

what I'm missing here?
I really would appreciate the help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to activate the service account in terminal before running the bq command.

Refer to link 
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account

you can also check the current active account on your terminal using

`gcloud auth list`